# Correlating SQL Profiler trace with code that caused query

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, trace, sql-server-profiler

I'm using SQL Profiler to trace the behaviour of an application that seems to be creating more transactions than it needs. The problem is, it's quite hard to correlate a particular line in the the trace with the C# code that caused it - is there an established way to do this? Is there a way for c# code to insert 'markers' into the SQL trace so that I can follow the story a bit more easily?

Answer (score 0):

Add `App=yourAppName` to connection string as follow and in sql profiler filter data based on `application name`

```
<add name="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=server_name;Initial Catalog=DBName;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=App_Name" />
```